# conectar python 3x a um servidor

Tags: python-3.x, socket

Eu tenho estudado python há algum tempo e eu estava tentando criar um script para se conectar a um servidor e obter uma resposta a partir dele, mas quando eu uso o código recebo um erro que não posso corrigir

O meu código

```
import socket
target_host = 'www.google.com'
target_port = 80

#criar um objeto socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#conectar o cliente
client.connect((target_host,target_port))

#envia alguma dados
client.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\R\NHost: google.com\r\n\r\n')

#recebe dados
response = client.recv(4096)

print(response)
```

O erro é:

```
client.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\R\NHost: google.com\r\n\r\n') TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import socket
target_host = 'www.google.com'
target_port = 80

#criar um objeto socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#conectar o cliente
client.connect((target_host,target_port))

#envia alguma dados
client.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\R\NHost: google.com\r\n\r\n'.encode())

#recebe dados
response = client.recv(4096)

print(response)
```

Você precisar usar `.encode()` pois o send requer bytes, não uma string

Comment: É supostamente isto que eu devo obter como resposta??


b'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: 54\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nDate: Wed, 01 May 2019 10:30:05 GMT\r\n\r\n<html><title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>'

Comment: Acredito que sim, já que foi uma requisição com falta

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer uma conversão no seu `send()` para o tipo `bytes` antes de fazer a requisição. Li no fórum em inglês que recomendam também o uso do `sendall()` para previnir problemas futuros.

```
import socket
target_host = 'www.google.com'
target_port = 80

#criar um objeto socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#conectar o cliente
client.connect((target_host,target_port))

#envia alguma dados
client.sendall(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\R\NHost: google.com\r\n\r\n')

#recebe dados
response = client.recv(4096)

print(response)
```

Comment: **b'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: 54\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nDate: Wed, 01 May 2019 10:30:05 GMT\r\n\r\n<html><title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>'**  É suposto eu obter isto como resposta?

Comment: Creio que sim, pois você concluiu a requisição com sucesso mas o servidor o qual você executou a ação te retornou um 'Bad request', ou seja, essa requisição não pôde ser atendida. Vide mais informações sobre  [**bad request**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)